# scipy optimize curve fit is not working for a simple fit

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I am trying to fit and subtract a curve to this dataset to remove long term variations, like this:

[image]

where the blue curve is the original (offset added to see the difference), then the orange is the result of fitting then subtracting. However, for some reason my fit is not working and the output has been looking like this:

[image]

and I'm not sure why it's failing... The code used to work (I generated that figure above) but for some reason it seems to have stopped and I don't think I changed anything.

Here is the code I am using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

df = pd.read_csv('stack1.csv')

def harmonics(day, A, B, C, D):
    return A * np.sin( (2 * np.pi * day)/365.25 ) + B * np.cos( (2 * np.pi * day)/365.25 ) +  C * np.sin( (4 * np.pi * day)/365.25 ) + D * np.cos( (4 *np.pi * day)/365.25 )

popt, pcov = curve_fit(harmonics, df['X'],  df['Y'])

Y_fit = list(np.asarray(df['Y']) - harmonics(np.asarray(df['X']), popt[0],popt[1],popt[2],popt[3]))
plt.plot(df['X'],df['Y']+0.7)
plt.plot(df['X'],Y_fit)
plt.show()
```

and here is the data I am trying to fit: [data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSB5xCnfP6F4GxE9Ln4KvHXuGq_z8VfRVgee2Sie9CQ6la-AJBDk7zpHUVtjyjjKz99mShXzhDEq_xi/pubhtml)

I'm not sure why it isn't working, and I have tried everything I could find (including changing the initial guess and the bounds) but have had no luck. Can someone please take a look and let me know how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: I took a look and I couldn't reproduce your first graph. I tried adding more terms to the harmonics (tip: use `*popt` when calling `harmonics` to generalize the number of arguments), tried adding shifts to the harmonics, changing the fit method and no luck. Plotting the model and data you can see the fit is OK. Do you have a previous version of your code, like a backup or a jupyter notebook checkpoint? Also, do you think you can play with your 4 parameters by hand to try and match the curve as closely as possible?

Comment: I just had an idea. Grab your first graph and extract the data points with some online tool (like https://automeris.io/WebPlotDigitizer/). The difference between the two graphs should give you the harmonics you initially got, right? Analyze it and try to fit it with your model. Supply these parameters as guesses to the model you showed here.

Comment: I don't think you get get along without special treatment of the jump at about 60.